# Keypress event for Japanese text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id").keydown(function () {

    });
})
```

This code perfectly works for everything(number,alphabet,symbol etc) except Japanese text. On key press it doesn't pass through this event. Does anybody know any solution?

Comment: what do you mean by 'Japanese text'? Japanese keyboard layout/input method?

Comment: The solution is to write your own IME in the webpage using JavaScript. This is not going to be easy, but it's actually very do-able.

Comment: @SethJeremiMalaki yes

Comment: @Pacerier I would not recommend that. First of all, it's a lot of work. Secondly, users are used to their OS's IME and have possibly customized it, changing that behavior is bad UX. Thirdly, how are you going to replace the OS's IME using your in-browser IME, when the OS IME intercepts keypresses?

Comment: computer does not know japanees

Comment: i think he is using some s/w for converting key board input to japanese equivalent

Comment: @ArunKillu Added from Region and Language

Comment: @deceze, It is a ton of work (assuming no 3rd party libraries), though I would not not-recommend it just because of that alone. OS IME only intercepts keypresses if we use the OS input box... try `body.onkeydown=alert(event.keyCode)` while in IME mode... A pure JS IME can be built with (or without) canvas. UX depends on use case. On one hand we have users who refuses to use anything but their OS jp IME. On the other hand we have users who may not even have an OS jp IME set. Some users may have an IME installed but they may not know how to use/enable it. Who is the target user?

Comment: @Pacerier You would need to have an *extremely important and narrow* use case to go through all this trouble; not only are you replacing the IME, you're also replacing the default OS text boxen and all select/copy/paste functionality that comes with it. If you do that, yes, I guess it's possible. Maybe for an internal app there's a case where it's worth it, but certainly not for the wider internet audience. Also, I probably wouldn't worry about users who don't have a JP IME set up, they are probably not going to want to type Japanese to begin with.

Comment: @deceze, JS is flexible. Even without replacing the default OS input, we have ways to get it done (by character detection). The choice is there, for a live demo look at http://www.google.com/intl/ja/inputtools/cloud/try/. Sujal asks if anyone knows a *solution*, and since there exists solutions, I think it inappropriate to say "no, we are stuck". Users without their own JP IME set up probably are not going to want to type a lot of Japanese. This doesn't mean they are not going to want to type *any* Japanese. I never had a JP IME set up, but at times I do want to type Japanese.

Comment: @Pacerier Sure, Javascript is flexible. But the demo you link to replaces at lot of default functionality with Javascript replicas. Yes, it's possible, but that demo has been produced by *Google*, a company with a ton of resources and talent. I contest that it's *not feasible* for a regular site. Also, we have no clue what the use case here is, so far it doesn't seem to me like the OP is particularly interested in or that it's necessary for him to produce an IME to solve his problem.

Comment: @deceze, yes it's possible and interested or not, there's many things we *can* do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's hardly anything you can do. "Japanese text" means an IME, which is a piece of software intercepting the keyboard input and helping you turn it into Japanese text. How this software interacts or doesn't interact with the browser and the browser's Javascript engine depends on the OS, IME, browser and the browser's Javascript engine. On some platforms the keypress is signaled through, in others it isn't. You can try binding to other events like `keyup` or `keypress`, some may be signaled even when using an IME.

The best you can do is to make sure you're not depending on keypress events and have fallback options if you can't intercept them; e.g. bind to `change` events on the text field as well and handle entire text changes, which *will* be triggered at the end of the IME input.

Comment: that means there is no way to use key up or down event for japanese text?

Comment: @sujal There is no way to *guarantee* you can use it, yes.

Comment: @sujal, you can always build your own IME *in* the webpage if you **really** need it. JavaScript these days are capable of doing that.

Comment: @deceze What do you mean by this one You can try binding to other events like keyup or keypress, some may be signaled even when using an IME.

The best you can do is to make sure you're not depending on keypress events and have fallback options if you can't intercept them; e.g. bind to change events on the text field as well and handle entire text changes, which will be triggered at the end of the IME input.? coz I'm also having problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937171/event-preventdefault-not-working-in-japanese-keyboard-vue?noredirect=1#comment86891024_49937171. Thanks

Comment: @sujal How did you resolve your problem? I'm having the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937171/event-preventdefault-not-working-in-japanese-keyboard-vue?noredirect=1#comment86891024_49937171

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, instead of prevent user input the text i set the input value to null because the api  `event.preventDefault();` is not working correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id").keyup(function () {
        this.value = ''
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I solved it using the input event.

```
//calculate the length of a character
function getLen(str){
    var result = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
      var chr = str.charCodeAt(i);
      if((chr >= 0x00 && chr < 0x81) ||
         (chr === 0xf8f0) ||
         (chr >= 0xff61 && chr < 0xffa0) ||
         (chr >= 0xf8f1 && chr < 0xf8f4)){
        //half width counted as 1
        result += 1;
      }else{
        //full width counted as 2
        result += 2;
      }
    }
    return result;
};

// trim the string by processing character by character
function getTrimmedString(theString, maxLength){
var tempLength = 0;
var trimmedString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
    tempLength = getLen(theString.charAt(i)) + tempLength;
    if(tempLength > maxLength){
        break;
    }else{
        trimmedString = trimmedString + theString.charAt(i);
    }
}
return trimmedString;
}

// limit the size of a field
function limitCity(){
var maxChars = 30;
var cityVal = $("#city").val();
var cityLength = getLen(cityVal);
if (cityLength >= maxChars) {
    var trimmedString = getTrimmedString(cityVal, maxChars);
    $("#city").val(trimmedString);
}
}

//bind the input event 
$("#city").bind("input", limitCity);
```