# Vue.js input field still accepts character input

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this code (input field) where I should only allow the user to input numbers but still accepts characters.

```
<div class="flexItem">
     <ui-textbox label="test" v-model="prospect.monthly_cost"
         name="testmonth"
         v-validate="`${vRequired}|decimal`"
         v-on:keypress="isNumber(event)"
         :invalid="errors.has('monthly_cost')"
         :error="errors.first('monthly_cost')"
         format="number"
     ></ui-textbox>
</div>
```

This only take effects or remove the characters in the field if hovered to another field. So I've added this one method to validate but is not executing it.

```
isNumber: function(evt) {
        console.log('Im in')
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && charCode !== 46) {
            evt.preventDefault();;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    },
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

This one now works with the help of Jacob's answer(by replacing `v-on:keypress="isNumber(event)"` to `v-on:keydown="isNumber"`, but my problem now if I switch my keyboard to japanese, it now accepts characters again. :S :S Any idea how to do that (restricting japanese characters)?

Comment: Can you share which ui library you are using?

Comment: @ShubhamPatel I'm sorry but it's a bit long, hihih. And I really believe that the actions/processes are just executed around this code.

Comment: I meant name of ui library from which <ui-textbox> is imported.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: (if you're using Keen UI) Keen UI textbox element doesn't support `keypress` event

https://josephuspaye.github.io/Keen-UI/#/ui-textbox

[image]

Problem 2: the `event` in `isNumber(event)` is unnecessary. Simply `isNumber` will do. (in scenario where you need to pass the event, the correct syntax is `isNumber($event)`)

suggestion to you :

change `v-on:keypress="isNumber(event)"` to `v-on:keydown="isNumber"`

---

Update: improve isNumber Function. Add 1 more validation to check if the key is number using [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). See `isNaN(evt.key)` below

```
methods: {
    isNumber: function(evt) {
        console.log("Im in");
        evt = evt ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (
            charCode > 31 &&
            (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) &&
            charCode !== 46
        ) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if(isNaN(evt.key)){
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it now executes the v-on but is still accepting characters.

Comment: @ramedju are you using `keydown` or `input` event? I realized that `input` wont work and has edited the answer to `keydown`. `v-on:keydown="isNumber"`

Comment: It's now good, I'm testing on the other field without my modification instead with the one I have modified. Hihi. Sorry.
But why is it that it's not accepting inputs from the numpad? It only accepts from the alphanumeric pad numbers. And my problem now is , it should also work or take effect on japanese keyboard.

Comment: @ramedju pls try the updates. not sure if it will work for japanese keyboard

Comment: Weeew, retested the above code but is not working japanese keyboard. It accepts Japanese characters :S

Comment: @ramedju https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029475/keypress-event-for-japanese-text

Comment: Thanks for the link. BUr How can I apply it on my function based on the answer?

Comment: @ramedju based on the answer, there's no reliable way to

Comment: Do you know what does this line means: " You can try binding to other events like keyup or keypress, some may be signaled even when using an IME. The best you can do is to make sure you're not depending on keypress events and have fallback options if you can't intercept them; e.g. bind to change events on the text field as well and handle entire text changes, which will be triggered at the end of the IME input." ??

Comment: @ramedju it means don't use the `keypress` event to handle the input key by key. Use the `input` event and handle the whole input value together. can you try typing japanese character into this https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/MGwbKw?editors=1010 ? when I give it `転キトヨ部識ートび123由民ず紙魅ヤ違8暮オ`, it becomes `1238` on unfocus.

Comment: Yes, my work also works this way, but what my client wants is it should not allow the user to input any character, it should only be all integers. Apologies for being a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding type="number"?

so:

```
<div class="flexItem">
     <ui-textbox label="test" v-model="prospect.monthly_cost"
         name="testmonth"
         v-validate="`${vRequired}|decimal`"
         v-on:keypress="isNumber(event)"
         :invalid="errors.has('monthly_cost')"
         :error="errors.first('monthly_cost')"
         type="number"
     ></ui-textbox>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `type="number"`, disables accepting comma on every. Instead of `100,000`, it will only displays `100000`. this helps somehow in trapping the japanese keyboard input.