# Event.PreventDefault() not working in Japanese Keyboard Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Following code is my trapping to only accept an integer value input from user:

```
isNumber: function(evt) {            
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

        if((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105) || charCode == 8 || charCode == 46 ||
        charCode ==36 || charCode ==35){  
            console.log("Im in if", charCode)                
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("Im in else", charCode)

            //evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            //evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;

        }
    },
```

**TEXTBOX**

```
<ui-textbox label="initial cost"
    name="cost"
    v-validate="`numeric|decimal`"
    v-on:keydown="isNumber"
    :maxlength = "18"
    :enforceMaxlength="true"
    value = 0.00
    format="number"
></ui-textbox>
```

This just works well when I'm using English keyboard format. But when I switch to Japanese, this doesn't take effect. `evt.preventDefault()` can do the trick for this, I've added the `evt.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `evt.stopPropagation()` to try its functionality, but still I'm unlucky enough and can't make anything to work.

IT'S NOT SAME WITH YOUR LINK GIVEN. The link you've given only works in English keyboards. But when you switch to Japanese, it will not work.

Comment: So the problem is that you are not going into the `else` code block ?

If you need the keycodes for compatibility issue, you can use this website to get them : http://keycode.info/

Comment: @Seblor I'm going inside the else code block, but is not preventing the user to input non-integer values.

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle or snippet ?

Comment: @Seblor The keycode returned is `229` but even I blocked it, it still displays.

Comment: @Seblor NO. This is not a duplicate. If you can try to switch your keyboard to Japanese Microsoft IME, you will see what I meant. I'm currently creating the JSFiddle.

Comment: When is this code invoked? Just to be sure for the obvious thing: It should be called when "keydown" happens.

Comment: @Eytibi Yes, during keydown. JacobGoh gave me this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029475/keypress-event-for-japanese-text , but how can I apply it on my function?

Comment: Does this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karjf5of/11/) work for you? I know this is not perfect, because it will reset the typing position. Beside that is there a reason why you cannot use the input type `number`?

Comment: @t.niese It works. But how can I insert or use it? And I'm using JS. Will update my question for the input box.

Comment: @ramedju According to the link from JacobGh you should bind your function (additionally) to the change event to ensure it is triggered also for Japanese keyboards.