# Automatically add comma in type=number vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way I can add comma automatically in `input type="number"` field in vue js? This is my only way to automatically change the IME options in Microsoft and disallowing the user to input Japanese character.

```
<ui-textbox label="initial" v-model="initial_cost"
    name="initial_cost"
    v-validate="`numeric|decimal`"
    type="number"
    v-on:keydown="isNumber"
    :maxlength = "18"
    :enforceMaxlength="true"
    value = 0.00
    format="number"
></ui-textbox>

isNumber: function(evt) {            
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        var charval= String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode);
        console.log(typeof evt);
        if((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105) || charCode == 8 || charCode == 46 ||
        charCode ==36 || charCode ==35){                
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

so if I the user input `1000`, display is `1,000`, `10000` to `10,000` and so on. I've seen a solution like this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734138/can-vue-js-add-commas-while-user-typing-numbers) but it seems that he is using `input type="text"` field? Is there any way I can apply this to my `type="number"` field in vue?

Comment: This is not supported by all the browsers. You need to have an input with `type=text` and then validate the number in the javascript I'm afraid. Please check this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315157/html5-input-box-with-type-number-does-not-accept-comma-in-chrome-browser. Also, in w3 specifications, they clearly state that this is up to the user agent. https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29

Comment: Only numbers and a decimal point are allowed in type number and as @kavindra states about it's up to the user agent so far no major browser has done that.

Comment: did you try to use that answer with a `type="number"` and it didn't work ?

Comment: @Taki Yes, I've already tried it, but failed to make it work.

Comment: @Kavindra I'm currently having type= text, but my problem is if the user uses japanese keyboard, my validation failed. You can check my concern here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937171/event-preventdefault-not-working-in-japanese-keyboard-vue

Comment: @Darkrum Yes, but I think it's possible in js?

Comment: @ramedju no it's not. You can't insert a comma into input type number.

Comment: @ramedju you have come a long way for this problem. =] I have a stupid/smart idea. how about making the input type `number` on focus and type `text` on blur ?

Comment: @JacobGoh Yes, so stupid for me to have come this far. Haha, anyways, what do you mean?

Comment: @ramedju this is indeed a difficult problem to solve. Don't put yourself down. for e.g. `:type="inputType"`, where `inputType` is a reactive variable, the value can be `text` or `number`. change the value of `inputType` on focus & blur. `@focus="inputType='number'"` `@blur="inputType='text'"`. when the input type is text, showing comma would become possible

Comment: @JacobGoh it now works, but it exceeded with my maxlength :S HAHA, too many problem for this lil issue. it also has a warning: `Property or method "inputType" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Comment: you can add another length validation on keydown. you'll need to add `inputType` to `data` as well

Comment: @JacobGoh Please add your comments as an answer :) Will accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section above, it's impossible to add comma to input with `type="number"`. It can display comma only when input `type="text"`.

You could make the input type `number` on focus and type `text` on blur, so that user can't type anything that isn't number, and comma is displayable when the user has finished typing.

add a new reactive variable in data called `inputType`

```
  data() {
    return {
      inputType: "text"
    };
  }
```

change/add some attributes in ui-textbox

```
<ui-textbox /*...*/ :type="inputType" @focus="inputType='number'" @blur="inputType='text'">
    <!-- ... -->
</ui-textbox>
```

This would make the `type` attribute dynamic. It would be type `number` on focus and type `text` on blur.

Comment: One last thing `v-on:keydown="`isNumber|maxlength=18`"`  is not doing well. Is that what you meant in the comment section above that I should do to enforce `maxLength`?　Because my `isNumber` validation is not working if I do it that way.

Comment: @ramedju something like this https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/RyWOJG?editors=1011

Comment: Thank you very much Jacob from helping me out from very first issue up until here :)　But why can't I delete a number?

Comment: @ramedju oh right, my bad. i've added a condition `if(isNaN(evt.key)) return;` to only check length when the key press is from a number. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/RyWOJG?editors=1011

Comment: Thank you very much. You really have saved me :)

Comment: One last problem, because if the input box has data, I have to double click it first before I can edit it. Do you have any idea why this happens? Is this because of `@focus` and `@blur` events?

Comment: @ramedju it's not happenning here. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/RyWOJG?editors=1011 . it's probably caused by something else

Comment: Can you please add some value on the field? I can't add any :) so that I can try there.

Comment: Weeew, I think my problem now is on my end, coz if i click on the field, the cursor just blink once and the focus is gone again :S